# GreenRobot EventBus data sharing between activities

Tags: android, events, android-activity, greenrobot-eventbus

I have a flow of activities that goes like this:

`ProductA` > `CreditCardA` > `PaymentA` > `ConfirmationA` > `DoneA`

Now, the confirmation screen needs information from `ProductA`, `CreditCardA` and `PaymentA`. However, I don't want to keep passing data that is useless for the previous activities. The `CreditCardA` needs to know nothing about the product, and `PaymentA` doesn't really care about credit cards or the product itself, only about the price and in how many months this price can be paid.

So I thought about using GreenRobot EventBus. From `ProductA`, a `PaymentFlowA` would be called (with no layout), which would register in the EventBus and receive from it data related to the payment flow.

Something like this:

```
public class PaymentFlowActivity extends BaseActivity {
  private CreditCard cc;
  // etc...

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startActivity(CreditCardA);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
  }

  @Subscribe
  void onCreditCard(CreditCardMessage ccMsg;) {
    cc = ccMsg.getCreditCard();
    startActivity(PaymentA);
  }

  // etc...
}
```

Now, I'm afraid about activity shutdown. What happens if `PaymentFlowA` is destroyed to free memory while the user is on, say, `PaymentA` or `ConfirmationA`? I'm afraid the instance state won't be restored properly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should use SharedPreferences. You will not be able to receive the data till the activity is created, at the best, and all of this seems to be too hack-ish.

Comment: @user2520215 Hm, I think I'll just pass the data horizontally : /

SharedPreferences doesn't seem like a good idea... how would I retrieve the data in the ConfirmationA?